# Contoso University Project: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on the Contoso University Project in .net core, and when I select 'Students' from the nav menu to see a list of students, and then the 'details' link on the page under the name of each student, I receive the following error:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.
```

It says the error is in StudentsController.cs on this line:

```
+
37            var student = await _context.Students
```

Any suggestions as to what the issue might be would be very helpful.

Here is my controller code:

// StudentsController.cs

```
// GET: Students/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var student = await _context.Students
                .Include(s => s.Enrollments)
                    .ThenInclude(e => e.Course)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(student);
        }
```

// SchoolContext.cs

```
    namespace ContosoUniversity.Data
    {
        public class SchoolContext : DbContext
        {
            public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
            {
            }
    
            public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
                modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
                modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
            }
        }
    }
```

// Student.cs (the model)

```
    namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
    {
        public class Student
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
            public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

// Index.cshtml (the list view)

```
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
    }
```

// Enrollment.cs

```
    namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
    {
   }
        public class Enrollment
        {
            public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    
            public int CourseID { get; set; }
    
            public int StudentID { get; set; } // foreign key
    
    // The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.
            public string Grade { get; set; } // nullable
    // The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.
    
            public Course Course { get; set; } // foreign key
    
            public Student Student { get; set; }
    
        }
    }
```

My data structure:

```
dbo.Course:
CourseId (PK, int, not null)
Title (varchar(255), not null)
Credits (int, null)

dbo.Enrollment
EnrollmentId (PK, int, not null)
StudentID( int, null)
CourseID (int, null)
Grade (varchar(255), null)

Student
Id(PK, int, not null)
FirstMidName(varchar(255), null)
LastName(varchar(255), null)
EnrollmentDate(datetime, null)
```

Comment: this is probably unrelated but, i have edited the question to remove the name signature at the end. its good that you are being polite and all, but thats not really required :) if someone posts an answer on this community, trust me, they have already decided to do it, for their own reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
var student = await _context.Students
         .Include(s => s.Enrollments)
         .ThenInclude(e => e.Course)
         .AsNoTracking()
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

Your passing in a nullable int?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
```

And in the class its just int

```
   public int ID { get; set; }
```

Try casting the nullable (int?) back to an (int) like

```
 var student = await _context.Students
            .Include(s => s.Enrollments)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Course)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == (int)id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I have tried this and it's not working still. It's mentioning a string, so I'm not sure think this has anything to do with it.

Comment: Try taking out the .include and .theninclude (just to narrow it down)....butKeep this is mind...it will be an error next.

Comment: Put your enrollment model in the OP...does it have Course?

Comment: @RobertYoung...see notes above

Comment: Hi @Chris yes, the enrollment model does have a course.
And I have tried commenting out the '.ThenInclude' and the error still remains. I have tried commenting out the '.Include' and the '.ThenInclude' - the error goes away but I get a different one saying there are now no enrollments (as expected).

Comment: I think the issue might be to do with the 'grade' data type - in the database it is set as 'varchar', but in the Enrollment.cs model its type is set to 'Enum'.

Comment: Yup - on Microsoft Docs page for Enum - "If no underlying type is explicitly declared, Int32 is used."

Comment: @RobertYoung...Glad you figured it out.

Comment: to get it working for now I have changed the 'Grade' data type to a string so it correlates with the database - not sure its the official solution and how it will fare with later stages of the tutorial, but seems good for now :) (see edit).